# Storing/updating Image along with entity data in spring boot/Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am new to spring-boot. I have a spring boot app and frontend in Angular 8 and postgres DB. I am using `MapStruct` for mapping between entity and DTO. I have a `Product` entity and creating new record and updating works fine. Now I want to include image in the entity also to be saved in DB. I have searched and found everybody is saying to use `MultipartFile` method but every solution contains only saving of image and not the entity data. Is there a way to save image along with entity properties? How does MapStruct behaves along with image as the image needs to be included in DTO? Any solutions?

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", indexes = {@Index(name= "part_number_index", columnList = "part_number", unique = true)})
public class Product extends UserDateAudit
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "part_number", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String partNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<ReplaceNumber> replaceNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProductManufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_model_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProductModel model;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProductCategory category;

    @Column(name = "cost", nullable = false)
    @DecimalMin(message = "Cost should be greater than 1", value = "1")
    private float cost;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    @DecimalMin(message = "Price should be greater than 0", value = "0")
    private float price;

    @Lob
    private byte[] image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapstruct knows the concept of update mappings. Checkout the [MapStruct Documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances). You can reuse the current mappings my means of `@InheritConfiguration`.

So

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {


// create method
@Mapping( target = "field1", source ="fieldA" )
@Mapping( target = "field2", source ="fieldB" )
Entity map( Dto in );


// update method
@InheritConfiguraton
void map( Dto in, @MappingTarget Entity out );

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sjaak. My mappings are working fine. I was looking for an example of entity having image file stored in db.

Comment: If the question is resolved, please mark the question as answered so others can benefit as well